# managing large projects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is more of a design question than a problem I'm trying to solve. I'm posting this here to get other people's opinion on the Design of the ASP.NET MVC framework.

To start with, I'll state the issues I have with the framework:

1. Html and code in views
2. Method names such as View() where one can't discern by looking at the name what it is doing and that it actually returns something
3. Too many overloaded methods that accept completely different parameters (like View())
4. Html Helpers - I don't believe Extension method were introduced for this use
5. ViewData

I'm not explaining in detail the issues I have have with the above in the hopes that there are others who see the problems I see. To be honest, I haven't anyone bring up these issues so I'm beginning to wonder if I'm alone :).

Someone somewhere must see/feel these issues when building large applications no?

Comment: Personally I like the framework a lot.  What is the point of the question?  Even if you find some people who agree with your unspecified concerns - what do you want to know?  Alternative frameworks to use?  How to work around specific weaknesses?

Comment: James, the point of the question as stated earlier was to get other people's opinion on the Design of the Framework itself.

Comment: Yes, alternative frameworks would be great! Not just different ViewEngines but different frameworks.

Comment: I think you're alone and even answering your specific concerns falls into subjective and argumentative territory.

Comment: The title utterly disagrees with the body of the question, and *then* the body is basically a rant. Take your choice between S&A and NaRQ.

Answer (score 3):

> Someone somewhere must see/feel these issues when building large applications no?

No, not really. At least - I don't call those as an issues.

---

> Html and code in views

Simple `if` or `foreach` won't cut Your head off. Way much easier than this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="uberRepeater" runat="server"> 
 <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate> 
 <ItemTemplate></ItemTemplate> 
 <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate> 
</asp:Repeater>
```

If You put there complex things, it's not fault of framework, it's fault of developer and his misunderstanding of mvc pattern.

> Method names such as View() where one can't discern by looking at the name what it is doing and that it actually returns something

Makes perfect sense to me:
[image]

It might not, if developer is not familiar with mvc pattern and conventions asp.net mvc follows.

> Too many overloaded methods that accept completely different parameters (like View())

It might seem like a problem. But with c# 4.0, if it bothers You, You can use named parameters to keep code readable.

> Html Helpers - I don't believe Extension method were introduced for this use

Extension methods indeed weren't introduced for html helpers. They were introduced to hook additionally logic to existing classes. It was must have feature in order to implement LINQ successfully.

Can't see that as an issue though.

> ViewData

Emmm.... huh?

---

But that does not mean issues don't exist. They do exist.
E.g. - huge part of Mvc V3 is about proper support for dependency injection.

Comment: I don't know why you're getting downvoted. It seems the OP doesn't understand convention based frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC Framework is powerfull. You have a complete control of HTML/client scripting output.

If you use it the right way and with a good infrastructure like SharpArchitecture you can achieve way more in user experience compared to any other framework (except silverlight).

In my experience, with the framework 4, asp.net mvc, a nice ORM (like hibernate), a DDD architecture, good patterns and an IoC, you save 30% of your project time and spend it on user experience.

Side note : SharpArchitecture is great architecture example, in fact, it is perfectible, but even out of the box, it can handle any size of project. With my experience since MVC1, I just can't imagine any large project without ASP.NET MVC, and it is more and more powerfull as the community is so creative and skillfull.

Answer (score 0):

By way of answering this, I'd direct you to a book that does quite a good job it: [Professional ASP.NET Design Patterns](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/productCd-0470292784.html) by Scott Millett.  The book takes the most popular patterns, including those documented by the "Gang of Four" and the enterprise patterns of Martin Fowler, and discusses them in terms of all ASP.NET app types, including MVC.

If he can't convince you that MVC offers advantages in partitioning user display, business logic, and data store, probably no one will

Answer (score 0):

@Buggieboy, I'm not questioning the MVC design pattern or the virtues thereof. My question is really related to the implementation/design of the ASP.NET MVC framework.

I guess I'm not talking to an objective crowd. Or as jfar says, I'm probably alone.